# How to grep a string after a specified line number?

Tags: linux, string, search, grep

I have a large text file, I want to see the lines containing `"time spent"` in this text file, I use:

```
grep -in "time spent" myfile.txt
```

But I'm interested only in the lines after 50000. In the output I want to see lines after 50000 and that contain "time spent". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can tail it, then grep:

```
tail -n +50000 myfile.txt | grep -in "time spent"
```

Comment: that does not work so well since it messes the line numbering up

Comment: Note the '+' sign. it seams useless but it means something else than tail -n 50000, it means: tail starting at line 50000 iso the lat 50000 lines

Answer (score 8):

**Answer for grepping between any 2 line numbers:**

```
Using sed and grep:

sed -n '1,50000p' someFile | grep < your_string >
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively you can use `sed`.
`sed` can be used to mimic `grep` like this:

`sed -n 's/pattern/&/p'`

By default `sed` prints every line even if no substitution occurs. The combinations of `-n` and `/p` makes `sed` print only the lines where a substitution has occured. Finally, we replace `pattern` by `&` which means replace `pattern` by itself. Result: we just mimicked `grep`.

Now `sed` can take a range of lines on which to act. In your case:

`sed -n '50000,$s/time spent/&/p' myfile.txt`

The format to specify the range is as follow: `start,end`
We just instruct sed to work from line 50000 to `$` which means last line.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. Note that `tail -n +2` (all lines starting at line 2) is very different from `tail -n 2` (only last 2 lines).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't catch that. Very good to know, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I do like the sed approach. Only one program needed, no pipe.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `head` + `grep` and group commands with `{...}` so that they share the same input:

```
{ head -n 50000 >/dev/null; grep -i PATTERN; } < infile
```

`head` doesn't consume the whole input, it gets only the first 50000 lines and dumps them to `/dev/null`; the remaining lines are processed by `grep`.
If you need the line numbers prepended (like with `grep -in`) you could use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>50000 && tolower($0)~/PATTERN/{print NR ": " $0}' infile
```