# Search a String and send mail if found in Shell Script

Tags: shell, search, logfile-analysis

I have to serch for an error like " Socket not open" in a log file named q2.log
and I have to send a mail if i find the string.
This process should happen at regular time intervel that i can schedule a chronjob,
But problem is for my first job lets assume  I read 1 to 1000 lines For next time I have to search from   1000 to remaining .How can i achieve it
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109580/how-to-grep-a-string-after-a-specified-line-number

Comment: Hi abasu Thanks for reply,Is it possible to store the last searched line number in a buffer

Comment: `grep -n pattern file | cut -f1 -d':'` will give you the line number