# Bash find occurrences of a value in a file that would not be enclosed in comments

Tags: bash, sed, grep, tail

Hi I'm trying to write a validation script that allows me to check settings in various tomcat configuration files. I can grep for the value I'm looking for, but being the commented out section can span multiple lines, i'm trying to look for the first occurrence of the start () comment values. 
Here is a snippet of tomcat's server.xml configuration file where the block is not commented out with  and I want to grep to find the value of SSLEnabled.

```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/opt/cloudhost/tomcat6/security/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
           ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,... [Sortened cipher list fro readability]" />
```

Now image if the above mentioned config was commented out, I would ignore it, and not consider the setting set. Therefore noting that the configuration holds the default value (if it has one of course, but not really relevant to my question):

```
<!--

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="/opt/cloudhost/tomcat6/security/keystore.jks" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
           ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,... [Sortened cipher list fro readability]" />
```

-->

I was thinking I can do something like this:

```
lineNumber=$(grep -n <somevalue> filename|awk '{ print $1 }')
```

based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109580/how-to-grep-a-string-after-a-specified-line-number), i tried

```
 tail -n $lineNumber server.xml| grep -n  '<!--'
```

which does return rows but appears to be starting at the top of the file and also missing some entries. Which I do not understand why.

I also tried:

```
sed '25,$!d' server.xml |grep -n '<!--'
```

which yields the same result

Comment: Provide some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: If you're just trying to find a pattern, use `grep`. If you're just trying to replace a pattern with a string all on one line, use `sed`. For anything else, for your own sanity just use `awk`.

Comment: For instance. Here is the line I'm grepping for:  
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
 I would like to find the first instance of "<!--" and "-->" after my grepped result (actually the line numbers they are on) then compare the line numbers. If the line number for "<!--" is less then then one for "-->", then I know what I initially grepped for is not commented out. Make sense?

Comment: Edit your question to show us some correctly formatted sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I ended up doing, and although it may not be the best solution, I did end up accomplishing my task.

```
cat $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml | sed '/<!--.*-->/d'| sed '/<!--/,/-->/d' | sed -n '/<.*[Cc]onnector.*port="8443"/,/\/>/p' | awk '/SSLEnabled=\"true\"/'|wc -l
```

I used sed to delete all the commented out blocks of the configuration and then grep'ed for the settings I wish to check. In the above case I'm looking for a uncommented section of the configuration file that has the connector port set to 8443 and SSLEnabled=true. I then counted the results and check if the count was equal to 1. If so it passed it, and if not it failed. This was because it was either not set or there were multiple ones defined and the configuration and that would need to be evaluated.

In the end, after using sed to delete the commented blocks from the pattern space, I searched for the desired value with desired pattern ([Cc]onnector) with sed suppressing all the output (-n) except for the matched pattern (p) and looked for the accompanying SSLEnabled setting using awk. Then counted the result (wc -l).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR>24 && /<!--/ {print; exit}' file
```

would print the first line containing `<!--` after line 24.

Comment: I'm confused. It appears to be showing the line prior.
echo "Ensure secure is set to true only for SSL-enabled Connectors: Section 1.6.9."
LineNumber=$( grep -n SSLEngine=\"on\" /etc/tomcat6/server.xml |awk '{ print $1 }')
LineNumberWithoutColon="${LineNumber%?}"
echo $LineNumberWithoutColon
awk '$LineNumberWithoutColon < NR && /<!--/ {print NR; exit}' /etc/tomcat6/server.xml

RESULT:
Ensure secure is set to true only for SSL-enabled Connectors: Section 1.6.9.
25
24 <- I was expecting 26, but its actually grabbing the line above.

Comment: Another problem I'm seeing is that I need a way to ignore the leading spaces during the search for "<!--" other wise I'm only seeing the ones without leading spaces

Comment: There is no block formatting in comments so if you have some formatted text to show us you need to edit your question to include it, not post it in a comment. Having said that, the awk script could not be simpler and it is not getting confused about line numbers, nor does it care about leading or trailing spaces around the search pattern so my best guess is that your input file was created on Windows and so contains spurious control-M characters which are corrupting your output. Run `cat -v` on the file to see them and run `dos2unix` or similar to remove them and THEN run the awk script on it.